# Convergence rate of mollifiers in Sobolev spaces (reference request).

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, convolution

Suppose I have a function $f\in W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R})$ and a mollifier $\phi$ with sufficiently many vanishing moments (I do not assume it has compactly supported Fourier transform). I suspect (see this question: [Convolution Error Estimate Reference Request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328697/convolution-error-estimate-reference-request)) that there is an estimate of the form
$$
\|f-\phi_{\epsilon}*f\|_{p}\leq C\epsilon^{k} \|f\|_{W^{k,p}}.
$$
Does anyone have a good reference for this (also the case $p=1$). (NB: also realise I can probably replace the full Sobolev norm with just $L^p$ norm of highest order derivative).

Comment: Just a remark, a compactly supported function with compactly supported Fourier Transform must be $0$. Hence the Fourier Transform of a mollifier cannot be compactly supported.

Comment: Is $\phi_\epsilon$ an approximation of identity ?

Comment: Ah sorry for confusion on both fronts - not assuming $\phi$ to be compactly supported (which seems to be the usual definition of mollifier) - just that it decays fast enough for moments to exist. Yes $\phi_\epsilon(x)=\phi(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon$.

Comment: its proven for $H^s$ spaces (more or less; i didnt check the specifics of the definition of a mollifier) in Majda & Bertozzi's book on fluids (vorticity and incompressible flow, part of lemma 3.5)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. The case of $p=2$ is the easiest one though - the $p=1$ case is the one I am most interested in.

Comment: I don't have a reference, but I think the easiest way to prove this estimate (let's say for $k=1$) is to write $\delta_0-\phi_\epsilon=(1_{(0,\infty)}-\Phi_\epsilon)'$ with $\Phi_\epsilon(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \phi_\epsilon(t)\,dt$ and use Young's inequality to get $\|f-\phi_\epsilon\ast f\|_p\leq \|1_{(0,\infty)}-\Phi_\epsilon\|_1\|f'\|_p$. Of course, $\phi$ has to decay fast enough to make the $L^1$-norm on the right side finite, but then it scales $\sim \epsilon$.